# How to put a variable inside cURL?

Tags: bash, curl

I created a script that will notify when a Flash drive was inserted problem is that when I pass the variable inside the curl. Got an error 400

This is the sample code I have.

```
GET_IP=`ifconfig en1 | grep "inet"`
```

Above is the variable

```
curl -d '{"color":"green","message":"'"$GET_IP"'","notify":false,"message_format":"text"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://test-rundeck.hipchat.com/v2/room/3909726/notification?auth_token=mytokenhere
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: You're missing the ending backtick on the first command.

Comment: Are you sure `$GET_IP` contains what you want? That line will set it to the entire line, e.g. `inet 192.168.3.102 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.3.255`. You probably just want the second field.

Comment: @Barmar sorry I got typo in the  post but in my code it has backtick. and for the GET_IP, i can use ifconfig en1 | grep "inet" | tail -1 for that.

Comment: Why haven't you fixed the typo in the post? That command still returns the whole line, not just the IP field.

Comment: I already inserted the backtick in the post, for now i need all the information for the ip.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that because I expected you to include `| tail -1` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `GET_IP` to the whole line from `ifconfig`, you need to get just the second field.

```
GET_IP=$(ifconfig en1 | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }')
```

I changed from a regexp match to `==` so it will only match `inet`, not `inet6`.

The `curl` line looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for this, Tho for testing purposes I need the all information for now. . But this solve my solution for after testing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by needing all the information? Doesn't it have to be in the format that the API expects it?

Comment: Found the problem, you're right the curl is correct. the GET_IP is the one messing in the curl. Tried your command and It works, Thanks mate